Task Scheduler not running after restart of VPC
I have 1 app that runs 24x7. I have configured Task Scheduler Task to Run the App at Logon and At Startup for Any User.
This all works perfectly on PC. But on VPC the system was restarted and the App didn't run as per Task Scheduler.
Here are the details of restart of VPC & Task scheduler -
The process C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe (pocket-biometri) has initiated the restart of computer pocket-biometri on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason:
Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
Reason Code: 0x80020010
Shutdown Type: restart
Task Scheduler



I found out that the restart was done by SYSTEM & i have the Task Scheduler to run for the another User & not SYSTEM.
So i configured another Task Scheduler to run for SYSTEM user.
